# How to do live.mywebsite.com => mywebsite.com/live via .htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wordpress

I need to do the following thing

1. Mapping this subdomain live.mywebsite.com/something to mywebsite.com/live/something
   for examples :
       `www.live.mywebsite.com/` ==> `www.mywebsite.com/live/`
       `http://live.mywebsite.com/` ==> `http://mywebsite.com/live/`
       `www.live.mywebsite.com/something` ==> `www.mywebsite.com/live/something`
       `http://live.mywebsite.com/something` ==> `http://mywebsite.com/live/something`
2. I want to hide a rewritten URL in web browser. This domain will be shown `www.live.mywebsite.com/something` instead of `www.mywebsite.com/live/something`

   3- Live is the name of a category from wordpress and there is no folder called 'live'

Here's what I have in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http:// www\.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

FYI I have added the subdomain via Parallels Power Panel.

One more thing, I can't install any plugin to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want `VirtualDocumentRoot`.  For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomains.mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias *.mywebsite.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%-3/
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This will use the third-to-last part of the domain name as a subdirectory under the normal webroot, so `live` for `www.live.mydomain.com` and `stuff` for `a.b.c.d.stuff.mydomain.com`.

Comment: Live is the name of a category from wordpress and there is no folder called 'live'. I don't think this is going to work with my wordpress. My question has been updated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lets see if I get this right:

You you have a URL composed of the following components:

```
(www.)category.domain.com/(something)
```

and this needs to be rewritten to

```
(www.)domain.com/category/(something).
```

I think you can do this with RewriteRules, and you seem to have gotten there partway already. Since you are going to hide the target URL anyway through a reverse proxy we can ignore any leading www, and we will just proxy to localhost.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}     ([^.]+)\.domain.com
RewriteCond %1               !www
Rewriterule (.*)             http://localhost/%1/$1   [P]
```

This proxies internally to localhost. Doing it this way has the advantage of not getting in a loop. The second RewriteCond is there to avoid proxying www.domain.com (which is probably where you administrate your site from...)

Wordpress adds it's own rules in .htaccss, and you need to have these in front of those. So you probably end up with something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}     ([^.]+)\.domain.com
RewriteCond %1               !www
Rewriterule (.*)             http://localhost/%1/$1   [P]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

You could combine however this with the wordpress .htaccess rules, so you don't need an internal proxy...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}     ([^.]+)\.domain.com
RewriteCond %1               !www
Rewriterule (.*)             index.php/%1/$1   [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

*Note: You need to change the first rule from matchin just index.php to matchin anything starting with index.php...*